# Enable complete debug logs for itunesstored on iOS 10, disabling replacing of data with <private>

Tags: ios, security, debugging, logging, ios10

On iOS 10, how can I make `itunesstored` not omit information from the console log, replacing it with `<private>`, as it does by default?

With the introduction of Unified Logging in iOS 10, possibly sensitive information is not written to the console log, as seen here.

```
itunesstored(iTunesStore)[88] <Notice>: ISURLOperation: Received headers for <private>:
<private>
itunesstored[88] <Notice>: LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Request failed with error: <private>
itunesstored[88] <Error>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: <private>
```

From my understanding the user can enable logging of this "private" information by installing a profile (.mobileconfig file) on the device. I have installed the *App Store/iTunes Store* profile (itmsdebugging.mobileconfig) provided by Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/

With it installed I still get the same `<private>` log messages as seen above.

I have tried on two separate devices. Other profiles, like the one for *CFNetwork*, works as expected though, enabling a lot of logging for those processes.

Comment: I don't think there is any profile you can grab to bypass the system hiding "sensitive" data. If I'm wrong I'd love to know how to do it.

Comment: Installing App Store/iTunes Store profile (https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/) provided by Apple worked for me.